# Semicolon in LIKE is not working for SQL server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this which is not retrieving the values from DB table even if the required value exist there.

Here's the query, which return zero rows:

```
Select * from SitePanel_FieldValue WHere SiteFieldIdfk =111
And SiteFieldvalue like '%!@#$%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?[]\;'',./%'
```

Following is the value in the table:

```
'!@#$%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?[]\;'',./'
```

When I run the query without ";" it is returning the value.

Can any one help me in figuring this out?

Thanks
Ritu

Comment: That value isn't like the one in your data. The value in your data starts with `!`, so is missing the leading left parenthesis (`(`) in your `LIKE`.

Comment: In *very* simple terms, `!@#` is *not* `LIKE '%(!@%'`. but `(!@#` *is* `LIKE '%!@%'`. Your query is like the former, not the latter.

Comment: Please see my edited query, this is not returning any rows.

Answer (score 0):

The value in your table is:

`!@#$%&*()-_=+{};; :"<>?[]\;'',./`

And the one in the `like` is:

`(!@#$%&*()-_=+{};;`

Starting with `(` it will never match, also you should scape the percent (`%`) in the middle of the string like this:

```
Select * 
FROM SitePanel_FieldValue 
WHERE SiteFieldIdfk =111
  AND SiteFieldvalue like '%!@#$\%&*()-_=+{};;%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: Query edited, check it

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple characters which are reserved when using [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) statement.
i.e. `%`, `_`, `[]`

Use the escape character clause (where I have used backtick to treat special characters as regular) such as

```
Select * from SitePanel_FieldValue WHere SiteFieldIdfk =111
And SiteFieldvalue like '%!@#$`%&*()-`_=+{}|:"<>?`[`]\;'',./%' escape '`'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your brackets (`[]`), it has nothing to do with semicolons. If we remove the brackets, the above works:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '!@#$%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?\;'',./' LIKE '%!@#$%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?\;'',./%' THEN 1 END AS WithoutBrackets,
       CASE WHEN '!@#$%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?[]\;'',./' LIKE '%!@#$%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?[]\;'',./%' THEN 1 END AS WithBrackets
```

Notice that `WithoutBrackets` returns `1`, where as `WithBrackets` returns `NULL`.

Brackets in a `LIKE` are to denote a pattern. For example `SomeExpress LIKE '[ABC]'` would match the characters, `A`, `B`, and `C`. If you are going to include special characters, you need to `ESCAPE` them. You have both brackets, a percent sign (`%`) and an underscore (`_`) you need to escape. You don't need to escape the hyphen (`-`), as it doesn't appear in a pattern (for example `[A-Z]`). I choose to use a backtick as the `ESCAPE` character, as it doesn't appear in your string, and demonstrate with a `CASE` expression again:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '!@#$%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?[]\;'',./' LIKE '%!@#$`%&*()-`_=+{}|:"<>?`[`]\;'',./%' ESCAPE '`' THEN 1 END;
```

If you wanted to use a backslash (`\` ), which many do, you would need to also escape the backslash in your string:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN '!@#$\%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?[]\;'',./' LIKE '%!@#$%&*()-\_=+{}|:"<>?\[\]\\;'',./%' ESCAPE '\' THEN 1 END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZWiuL9II)

Answer (score -2):

I think the issue is actually with the backslash.  This is an escape character and so if you want it to be included, you have to put it in twice.

```
Select * from SitePanel_FieldValue WHere SiteFieldIdfk =111
And SiteFieldvalue like '%!@#$%&*()-_=+{}|:"<>?[]\\;'',./%'
```

Comment: Backslash works as a escape character in **SQL** only if you use `ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: I think backslash is the DEFAULT escape character, if you want anything else you need to specific it.

Comment: It is not, @AaronReese , there is no default escape character. `SELECT CASE WHEN '[]' LIKE '\[\]' THEN 1 END` doesn't return `1`.